# Couchbase cluster update visibility on clients

Tags: python, couchbase, libcouchbase

I have the following scenario:

- I have a domain name `couchbase.myorg.com`
- The record has 1 A record, say `10.0.0.5` that is one node in the Couchbase cluster.
- The couchbase cluster has 5 nodes 10.0.0.5 - 10.0.0.9
- The client uses this connection string: `couchbase://couchbase.myorg.com/my_bucket`
- I am using the [couchbase python client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/couchbase) which uses the libcouchbase C library.

The question:

Is a client restart required to get cluster updates in the following scenarios:

1. If `10.0.0.6` is removed from the cluster.
2. If `10.0.0.6` is removed from the cluster and replaced with another node at `10.0.0.10`.
3. If `10.0.0.10` is added to the existing 5 nodes in the cluster.

Comment: According to http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/sdk/c/failure-considerations.html this is not necessary:  `After the offending node has been failed over the client will detect the node down within a matter of seconds. When the SDK detects a node has been failed over, it will remove it internally from its list of cluster nodes.`

Answer (score 1):

No a client restart is not needed when the topology of the Couchbase cluster changes.  Please note, you should always provide multiple Couchbase Server nodes to the connection string though.  In the event the provided Couchbase Server node is offline at client start-up the client will have additional nodes to attempt to contact.

You are not required to enumerate or pass all Couchbase cluster nodes to the client. The client only needs to know about a single node which is a member of the cluster. Once the client has connected to the node, it will query that node about the cluster topology, which in turn contains information about all Couchbase nodes and the services they contain.

http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/python/managing-connections.html#concept_ppz_lhq_44